# Multiple notification for same call

Tags: flutter, dart, callkit, videocall, flutter-webrtc

pals

I have used [flutter_callkit_incoming : 2.0.0+1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming) for the call notification on the flutter side. It works perfectly on every device. But in some cases, it sends multiple notifications for the same call. And it happens eventually. Don't know the exact test case in which the repeated notification showing.

Thank you in advance